# JavaScript progress bar : Require is not defined

Tags: javascript, dom, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I'm trying to use progress bar in my application from this site : https://github.com/kimmobrunfeldt/progressbar.js

I've written below code in my application :

```
var element = document.getElementById('example-clock-container');
        element.innerHTML = '<header id="clock-seconds"></header>';
        var textElement = document.getElementById('clock-seconds');

        var ProgressBar = require('resources/js/progressbar.js')

        var seconds = new ProgressBar.Circle(element, {
            duration: 200,
            color: "#492B2B",
            trailColor: "#F3E4D0"
        });

        setInterval(function() {
            var second = new Date().getSeconds();
            seconds.animate(second / 60, function() {
                textElement.innerHTML = second;
            });
        }, 1000);
```

But it throws me an error saying

> Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

How can I get reference to object given it's file name ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Look under

https://github.com/kimmobrunfeldt/progressbar.js#loading-module

If you're not using module loader 
try the code under
"Global variable"

else, use module loader

http://requirejs.org/docs/start.html

Answer (score 0):

The require is not available on standard Javascript, but it is part of Node.js and used there to load javascript modules ( more info about node.js require: http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html ).

To use the require in your standard Javascript, you need to include the module loader separately. In this case I think you are missing this: http://requirejs.org/docs/start.html